# hyundai tucson squeal that stops at highway speed

Tags: noise

My 2007 Hyundai Tucson is making a squeal/squeak at low speeds. It seems to make the noise at the same rate whether I'm accelerating or pushing the brakes. When I'm stopped it makes no sound, and after hitting highway speeds it stops and doesn't start up until the car is restarted. As the driver, it sounds like it's coming from either the front passenger side or under the passenger floor board. Any ideas?

edit:
here's a video of the sound. try not to be too distracted by the awesome camera work. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghfB2Ah13Z0

it doesn't sound like the other bad wheel bearings sounds i've seen on youtube, but i'm not saying it's not.

Comment: The symptoms are consistent with a worn wheel bearing. Have those checked out. Some places may even do it for free.

Comment: My Tucson is making exactly the same noise! What did it turn out to be and how much was it to fix? Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem! Replaced the bearings and sound is still there

Answer (score 2):

It certainly sounds like a wheel bearing from your description. An easy test for a wheel bearing is too drive the vehicle on a straight clear road at around 20-30mph. Mindful of traffic, turn the steering as much as possible to one side. After turning the steering one way repeat the steering of the vehicle as before the other way. When weaving on the road make a note of the wheel bearing noise. As the weight of the vehicle is transferred to the outside of the vehicle on turning, the wheel bearing if defective, will now sound louder. By weaving and listening to the bearings you should be able to identify a defective bearing. This test applies to both front and rear axles. Only carry out this test when it safe to do so, and it is better still if you have an assistant to monitor the traffic conditions. If this proves inconclusive then your next stop would be an inspection at your favourite repair shop.

Comment: could you check out this video of the sound? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghfB2Ah13Z0

Comment: I have listened to the video. The sound on the video is a suspension bush or spring noise. Visual inspection required.

Comment: Just a thought, have an assistant rocking the car from the side may very well produce the sound when the vehicle is stationary. You can then look underneath and around the vehicle to pinpoint whats causing the noise.